# Stop Image Marque When Mouse touch it

Tags: html, css, web

Here's My Website https://therealandy0074.github.io/therealandy0074/ at github pages
And On The bottom There is a auto scrolling image on it
i want when mouse touch the picture, its stop scrolling
i dont find any reference on google and dont know what keyword 
can u tell me the keyword?
im using this code that found in way2tutorial.com

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
    <img src="https://therealandy0074.github.io/therealandy0074/testi/1.jpg" width="120" height="80" alt="Natural" />
  </marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('marquee img').on('click',function(){

    var mysrc= $(this).attr('src');
    
    $('.zoom_img').attr('src','');
    
    $('.zoom_img').attr('src',mysrc);

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"
            onmouseover="this.stop();"
           onmouseout="this.start();">
           <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/google.jpg" height="100">
           <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiEEbvzeGDaJ7bULe5vVEMHJp3Mmdk_VbMVteInDQut6u37eMn" height="100">
           <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShcf4OFdDZqZA2qynsdV3PNuMCCne57WTX8jzOzvgmDF9p-ao1qA" height="100">           
  </marquee>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/google.jpg" class="zoom_img" width="100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"
           onmouseover="this.stop();"
           onmouseout="this.start();">Add your images here</marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how when the mouse clict the picture is expanded

Comment: Can you write your question in brief?

Comment: okay, my first question is solved, but another comes to my mind, when you try to click the pic, it's doing nothing, my question is how when we click the pict, its zooming the pic or showing the real pict without leaving the page, so its like an popup

Comment: I have added code what you wanted.. please check. I have used bootstrap modal for showing popup

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
<img src="../jix/img_nat.png" width="120" height="80" alt="Natural" />
  </marquee>
</body>
</html>
```